# Enabling default timestamp in elasticsearch

Tags: timestamp, kibana, elasticsearch

I want to organize my data in elasticsearch and visualize it using kibana.I am using elasticsearch 1.4.4 and Kibana3.

The elasticsearch for all my data is `bits` and I have two document types `aaaa` and `bbbb`. I run the below script at the beginning and expect a timestamp field of the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` with value as the time of insertion of the document. MY understanding is that each document will have a timestamp field. I can't see this field in kibana. Kibana does say 
`mappings._default_._timestamp.enabled` however I can't seem to be able to set that as the `index` timestamp for my dashboard. What am I doing wrong here.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/bits -d '{
"settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 2
},
"mappings" : {
    "_default_":{
        "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "store" : true,
            "path" : "post_date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        }
    }
  }
}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/bits/aaaa -d '{
"settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 2
},
"mappings" : {
    "_default_":{
        "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "store" : true,
            "path" : "post_date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        }
    }
  }
}'
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/bits/bbbb -d '{
"settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 2
},
"mappings" : {
    "_default_":{
        "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "store" : true,
            "path" : "post_date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kibana4 doesn't show _fields by default.  Go to Settings->Advanced, and add "_timestamp" to the "metaFields" option.

For Kibana3, it was reported as [a bug](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/542) and closed in favor of using Kibana4.

Comment: I am using Kibana3 and elasticsearch 1.4.4 as mentioned above.